# Comparar inputs com a mesma classe e sem id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, tenho a seguinte estrutura

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Valor1</th>
    <th>Valor2</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Gostaria de comparar se o valor digitado na coluna `valor1` ja existe na coluna `valor2`, porem a unica forma de indentificação que tenho é a class `texto`

Comment: Você não consegue adicionar outra classe, id ou atributo data nesses inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

o conselho que lhe dou, é que intere cada linha da tabela, e use as mesmas como scopo.

```js
var validar = document.getElementById("validar")
validar.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  // obtendo todas as linhas, para então interar as mesmas.
  var linhas = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
  [].forEach.call(linhas, function (linha, indice) {
    // buscando todos os inputs dentro da tr atual
    var inputs = linha.querySelectorAll(".texto");
    // verificando se o valor dos inputs é igual.
    if (inputs[0].value == inputs[1].value) {
      alert("inputs da linha " + (indice + 1) + " possuem o mesmo valor.");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Valor1</th>
      <th>Valor2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input id="validar" type="button" value="Validar"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
      <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer desta forma, o mesmo html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Valor1</th>
    <th>Valor2</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Com o seguinte código jquery:

```
$(function(){  
    $('.texto').on('change', function(){

    var col1val1 = $('.texto').eq(0).val();
    var col1val2 = $('.texto').eq(2).val();

    var col2val1 = $('.texto').eq(1).val();
    var col2val2 = $('.texto').eq(3).val();

    if(col1val1 == col2val1 && col1val1 != ''){
        alert('Valor igual ao da outra coluna!');
    }

    if(col1val2 == col2val2 && col1val2 != ''){
        alert('Valor igual ao da outra coluna!');
    }

  });
})
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/tw2b9mq8/11/

Utilizando o 'eq', você consegue pegar o item "texto" que você quiser.

Quando você usa o seletor '.texto' ele pega todos os elementos desta classe, então você pode escolher entre estes elementos utilizando a função 'eq'.

Comment: O segundo `&&` é redundante, pois se ambos são iguais e um deles é diferente de vazio então ambos são diferentes de vazio.

Comment: @Isac obrigado, alterei o código.

Answer (score 0):

Eu verifico se o campo digitado por ultimo esta na coluna 1 ou 2 e dependendo de qual for, eu uso o atributo `next()` ou `prev()` para comparar o valor digitado com o da coluna oposta.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.texto').on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).parent().next().find('.texto').lenght) {
      if($(this).val() == $(this).parent().next().find('.texto').val()) {
        alert('valores iguais');
      }
    } else {
       if($(this).val() == $(this).parent().prev().find('.texto').val()) {
        alert('valores iguais');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Valor1</th>
    <th>Valor2</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
    <td><input class="texto" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```